# Communiacting with USB device on linux

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

I need to communicate with a USB device. The communication is wrapped in both Windows and Linux by file I/O, and the tricky part seems to be deducing the device path name.

On Windows I use Setup API (`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` and friends), discover the path to my device, and the communication seems to work as expected.

On Linux I use udev API (`udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem` and friends), and it seems to find my device. At least I correctly deduce its parameters (idVendor, idProduct, and etc.).

However I can't communicate with it. The path I deduce is of the form like `/dev/bus/usb/001/078`, and I can open it (via `open` function).

But it doesn't behave like the target device. The USB device is expected to communicate in terms of so-called USB reports (i.e. kind of messages).
In practice I see that when I open it I can read 82 bytes of data (which is not expected), and I can't send anything (although I've opened the file with `O_RDWR` flag).
After some investigation I discovered that those 82 bytes is in fact the `USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` structure.

So, it looks that the file I've opened is actually a file which contains the device parameters, and has nothing to do about communicating with the device itself.

What is the correct way of deducing the path to the device?

Comment: That is the device. It has more than just read and write. On Linux, everything that is more complicated than read or write is `ioctl`. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-api/usb/usb.rst

Comment: I'm pretty much sure there's an abstraction layer that allows to work with USB devices via read/write.
Seen several examples, they suggest it. Perhaps I need to open another path, which would be operated by another driver.

Comment: Which examples?

Comment: https://github.com/libusb/hidapi/blob/master/linux/hid.c

Note `hid_write` is actually `write`. There's another matter of how to build valid messages to write (must comply to special format), but this is another story.

Comment: It seems to open a [hidraw](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hid/hidraw.txt) device file, which you get if the device is attached to the hidraw kernel driver for HID devices, not the generic USB driver. So it's a different kind of device file. In fact hidraw supports both USB and Bluetooth HID devices.

Comment: Right, this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. But can't get the actual path. For some reason can't enumerate HID devices on the system (enum is empty).

Comment: Where are you looking for HID devices?

Comment: I use `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem`. If I specify "hidraw" then nothing is discovered. It's on Ubuntu which runs under WSL.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any hidraw devices. Is the hidraw driver loaded? Does Ubuntu actually know about your plugged in HID devices? I expect that Windows does all that stuff because you are not really running Linux but just pretending to. The actual OS on your computer is Windows.

Comment: You can run lsusb to see what USB devices Ubuntu knows about. Which does not mean they are all connected to the hidraw driver or that the hidraw driver is loaded

Comment: You're right. It's somewhat complicated. The USB device is definitely plugged, then it's emulated in linux vis usbipd. Now, I can see this device via `lsusb`.

So, you say for some reason the hidraw driver isn't loaded. Maybe. I'm curious however why/how other apps can access it? There's a python app, which does succeed to communicate with it via hidraw interface

Comment: is there a /dev/hidraw0 for example?

Comment: no, can't see it. Nothing that starts with /dev/hid*

Comment: You may need to check whether CONFIG_HIDRAW is enabled in the kernel configuration; if it's set to m then you may need to load the module. Or maybe it is loaded but it doesn't know that it's supposed to access this device. Can't try anything for you as I don't run WSL

Comment: On Windows are you accessing the device as a raw HID device (whatever the Windows equivalent of hidraw is) or as a USB device? Because there are also other possibilities on Linux - the hid-input driver which is normally used for mice and keyboards and touchpads etc, and the hiddev driver which I don't know anything about. On Linux there are often many ways to do things and some are more popular/better maintained than others